# How to $or with reactivemongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

How to create a query with reactiveMongo with the operator `$or` in order to find document by a field OR an other one. thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please ask a good question and check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Reading the official documentation, you can find how to translate using the driver : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/.

Comment: this is helpfull thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With BSON syntax:

```
BSONDocument("$or" -> BSONArray(
      BSONDocument("name" -> "JON"),
      BSONDocument("surname" -> "Tailor")
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the syntax

```
query = Json.obj(
  "$or" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj("distributor.PhoneNb" -> phone),
    Json.obj("client.PhoneNb"->phone)
  )
)
```

Comment: Not for BSON syntax